# I cannot find the currentUser() in parse

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I am making an app so whenever somebody can press the add button and then type in one of their family member's emails and it will add the email to an array in parse. This is what my code looks like:

```
    func Save() {
    PFUser.currentUser()!.addObject(memberName.text!, forKey: "Family_Emails")


}
```

memberName is the TextField's IBOutlet connection name
"Family_Emails" is the parse array object I have set up

Whenever I click the save button it doesn't do anything. What do I do?

Comment: Where do you save the user object ???

Comment: And have you checked the function is called?

Comment: Im saving it in a parse array and I have definetely called it

Answer (score 0):

You're just not calling save on the user object.

```
PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects